# how to map values from a long cloumn of a datatable (1500+ rows) to another big datatable (27k+ rows) and filter common rows?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

I have two datatables `dt1` and `dt2`. `dt1` has 1500+ rows and `dt2` has 27k+ rows. there is a common column *customer No.* in both of them. I want to find the common rows in both datatables. My approach is to store the smaller datatable into a dictionary and then filter the bigger datatable using dictionary[customer No.] as a mapping variable in a LINQ query. But I am afraid it might take too much time. is there any faster approach possible for it?
the code I am using is given below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new { Key = 'Cust No', Value = 'Value col' }).ToDictionary(kvp => (string)kvp.Key, kvp => (string)kvp.Value);

List<string> accountNos = dict.Keys.ToList<string>();

IEnumerable<DataRow> filteredRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => "some condition");

filteredRows.ToList().ForEach(r => r.SetField("col name", accountNos.Any(r['Cust No'].ToString().Contains)));
```

Comment: use the join operator to do an inner join

Comment: A Linq join uses a Hash just like the key in a dictionary so I don't think there is going to be much of a time difference between just using a Linq join and using you proposed method.

Comment: Database systems happen to be optimized for things like this, unsurprisingly. If `dt1` and `dt2` come from a database, consider writing a query instead rather than reinventing the wheel. 1500 or even 27000 rows wouldn't typically be considered big sets.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the datasets are coming from excel. BTW, using join helped and now my code works upto the mark.